# Why my HTML link background does not change to red when mouse clicked on it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a very simple Javascript (jQuery) code, which just add a class name to the HTML link `<a>` element when the link is clicked, then use CSS to **change the link background to red**.

You will see in my code, I defined the background color for HTML `link visited, hover, active`  . The Javascript (jQuery) code is just to `addClass()` to the `<a>` link tag to change the background color to red by using CSS if the link has been clicked.

**My code is** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/7/) on **jsfiddle**, Why it does not work?

**---------------New problem------------------------**

Seems the thing get different if I put the link inside a table (as a content of `<td>`), like [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/27/) shows, why now the background does not change to red???? (But the font size did change, strange, seems partly highlighted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, jQuery objects have `.addClass` available. So not `this.addClass`, but `$(this).addClass`. `$(this)` creates a jQuery object from an element.

Secondly, `a .highlight` means: any descendants of `<a>` elements with a class of `highlight`. You want `<a>` elements which have that class *themselves*, so use `a.highlight` (without the space).

http://jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/10/

Comment: Ah, yup, I was about to give the same answer. But you explained it better than I would have. +1

Comment: Could you also help on the similar case here, the only difference is I put the link to a table <td>, it does not show the highlight background still, Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/27/

Comment: @Leem.fin: You should never use an ID twice in one document - then you destroy the idea of an ID (it should be unique). Also, adding `!important` in CSS makes a rule superior to others. I used a *class name* instead of an ID: http://jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/29/.

Answer (score 1):

`addClass` is a jQuery function; `this` is a native DOM element.

You need `$(this)`

Answer (score 1):

you need to use $(this)

```
$("#my-link").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("highlight");
});
```

Comment: Could you also help on the similar case here, the only difference is I put the link to a table <td>, it does not show the highlight background still, Here is the code: jsfiddle.net/YJH9g/27

Answer (score 0):

For your second question:
You can not use an id multiple times! What you can do is use classes:

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
   <td class="col">
       <a class="my-link" href="#">Home</a>
    </td>
    <td class="col">
       <a class="my-link" href="#">Help</a>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

js

```
$(".my-link").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('highlight');
});
```